# Will installing/ running Bootcamp on my Mac require reinstalling OS X?

Tags: macos

I'm not getting a clear answer out of Google and would like to know if I'm going to have to reinstall my Mac operating system when attempting to get Bootcamp going on the system.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't. I've got bootcamp on my Mac at home and did not have to reinstall my Mac OS.

Answer (score 3):

Boot Camp creates a separate partition on your hard drive through "non-destructive partitioning", that is, by taking a chunk out of the free space left on your hard drive. You should always make a backup first, just in case, but the expected result is that you will simply end up with two partitions instead of one on your hard drive. One will be for Boot Camp, and the other will be for Mac OS X and all of your existing files/applications/etc.

See [this Apple support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11131). Also when you start Boot Camp Assistant it will present a guide that you can print out to follow along with while setting it up.